# c++ gui window cross platform

Tags: c++, user-interface, window

I would like to make c++ that will work both on Linux and windows as I understand if I use the win32 template in visual studio then it will only work on windows is there something built into c++ like java's jframe that I can use. Also I would like to use any external library at this time.

Comment: There's nothing built into the standard C++ libraries, but there are many choices of add-on packages.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cross-platform application & UI development framework called **Qt**. I think it meets your requirements. [Click here for more info.](https://www.qt.io/application-development/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cross platform alternatives [QT](http://qt.io), [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org), [Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org). I have used **QT**, it is intuitive with a huge collection of tools to use in your code. The others are also popular but I have never used them.

Answer (score 0):

I make used of wxWidgets due to it's cross platform and even cross architecture, native look on the OS where it appear. Binary application yields by wxWidgets is small enough thus make it possible to linking statically as portable application. Qt produce huge binary if linked statically (and may be violate qt licensing scheme).

Another reason are licensing flexibly, well documentation and supported by huge community arround the world. wx is considered as mature framework since it first release about 20yrs ago. It's use standard C++ syntax and preprocessor that will make you easily switch from plain C or C++.  Complete library are available ranging from appeal window GUI, string, network, stream, webview, xml, and wx is playing very well with 3rd party library as such database SOCI, Asio, etc ....

You may try start to code with wxWidgets easily using Eclipse-IDE and wxFormBuilder as GUI designer. Plese check my experience for ease setup it's IDE+Toolchain. This wx installer can be used do develop, test and run wx application on Linux desktop, and then deploy the binary on Raspberry Pi is available for another board target beside Linux x86_64.

http://yasriady.blogspot.co.id/2016/01/raspberry-pi-toolchain.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a long list of both active and dead cross-platform C++ UI libraries here: https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/